# Cross server joins in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

Is there a way to join tables in different databases that reside on different servers without linked servers?

If linked servers is the only option are there drawbacks/warnings/anything I should consider when setting linked servers in clusters?

Thank you.

Comment: Run the query from the server that is going to hit the most rows locally.

Answer (score 2):

Linked servers are pretty much the only game in town.  The major drawback is performance... your server cannot optimize a query to linked servers very well, and of course the data transfer rates and index utilization are severely hampered.

When I have had to do something like this, I try to grab all the remote results I would be using through simple queries and store the data locally in indexed temp tables.  The initial draw can be slow but then I can use the data as needed.  But really, any sort of complex query across servers should be avoided if at all possible.  A sub-second query can end up taking minutes or longer.

Comment: will these drawbacks only affect me when querying server1 being connected to server2, and running queries on a server I am connected to will still be the same?
Basically what I am asking is will just setting up linked servers affect any current performance?

Comment: It's query-specific.  If your query references tables from more than one server, the performance hit will be there.  The more complicated the interaction is between the table data and the volume of data are significant factors in how bad the hit is.  Selecting 20 rows from a remote server might not be noticeable, but joining it to a local table, then joining a local table to the remote table under a join condition that is not optimized for over a remote connection is a good way to lose hair.